# copy datase objects (pk, fk, roles, indexes, ...) from database to another database

Tags: sql-server, database, talend, database-indexes

I used to be on MS SSIS there is "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task Editor" and i can choose which object i can transfert (pk, role, indexe, schema and data). 
Now i'm on Talend open studio and there is no component like this.

I would like to copy indexes, pk, schemas and data from a SQL Server database source to another SQL Server db destination.

How can i get data, indexes, pk and schemas from source db and set them to destination db? 
i tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652148/how-to-copy-indexes-from-one-table-to-another-in-sql-server?newreg=6073700fc0914b10a35434e77334940d) but the script generated is for CREATE (create db, tables, ...) and the txt file was 10Gb 
I have a db with 520 tables.

Comment: Not sure... are you asking on how to clone a database?

Comment: thank you for your reply No, just copying some objects.