# Is there a way to preserve indexes and keys of SQL table when performing a copy activity using azure data factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Trying to perform a copy activity from onprem sql to azure sql.
The source database table has few indexes and keys and when I perform Copy activity to azure sql by Auto-generate new table, indexes and keys are missing on destination table.

Comment: I assume one way is to create the table first using stored procedure with all the indexes and keys

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Sorry @JayGong , your answer didn't give me any new context to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the parameter statements in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#azure-sql-database-as-the-sink),there is no guarantee that the index and key will be transferred in ADF copy activity.

As you mentioned in your comment,you could have to create them by yourself,such as in the stored procedure which could be executed in ADF copy activity.

More clues,please refer to these threads:

1.https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/copy-table-one-database-another-database/

2.[How to copy indexes from one table to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652148/how-to-copy-indexes-from-one-table-to-another-in-sql-server)